# how to encrypt a file While downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, encryption

I am having a problem to encrypt a file while downloading.I am using this code to download the database to excel file

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = graphids.ToList();
                gv.DataBind();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=GraphTable.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

Now After this code file is automatically downloaded to download folder of my Pc and now i want to encrypt this xls file before downloading?

Comment: I assume you write something to htw, right?

Comment: Check out this link -- [File-with-encryption](http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-upload-file-with-encryption-and.html). Hope, it may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use System.Security

```
FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename, 
                    FileMode.Open, 
                    FileAccess.Read);

    FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, 
                    FileMode.Create, 
                    FileAccess.Write);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
```

you can use **MemoryStream** and wrap that in a **CryptoStream** to encrypt data ...

Comment: Can u plz elaborate your answer?

Comment: Look at the sample here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx